# Which events get fired in the page being loaded using $load method of jQuery?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-events

Here is index.html

```
        <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow','id="container"',  function(){       
            $.mobile.activePage.find('id="content-container"').load("content.html", function(){ 
                $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
            }); 

        }); 

    </script>
```

The content.html page has to retrieve data from server when it was loaded.

Which event is fired in content.html page when the above code executes?

---

I already tried the following events but none of them are working

1. **pagebeforeshow**
2. **pageshow**
3. **deviceready**
4. **pagecreate**
5. **pageinit**
6. **pageload**

Comment: Did u tried pagechange

Comment: yes, pagechange also not get fired...

Comment: I am not able to understand your code.Use this link i think u may get help from it  http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-YfTMZd-Ta0o/UGpmlFqH_4I/AAAAAAAAATI/BwA8SSSFGkM/s1600/fig1-jqm-page-eventsF.png

Comment: '$('content').load('conent.html')'..when content.html beging loaded using ajax, **fire event in content.html while loading** to fill data..

Comment: Did you find your solution

Comment: no, visited your above link but it describe jquery-mobile life cycle..events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them will trigger because they are not linked to load function. You should use jQuery Mobile version of that function called: loadPage. It is a wrapper function for function load.

This is the official link:  http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.loadPage/

In this case page event order would look like this:

1. **pagebeforeload**
2. **pagebeforecreate**
3. **pagecreate**
4. **pageinit**
5. **pageload**

To correctly detect pageload and pagebefpreload events use them like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeload', function(){    
    console && console.log("pagebeforeload!!");
});                 

$(document).on('pageload', function(){    
    console && console.log("pageload!!");
});
```

Read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile/)**, you will also find a working example.